# SAP UI5 Application - Scrollbar issues

Tags: sapui5

In SAP UI5 application, every table has its own scrollbar. There is one page level scrollbar as well. Problem is, to see all the rows of the table I have to use, both the scrollbars. For example, if I am scrolling the table, once it reaches the bottom (of the page not table), scroll disappears. Now to see remaining of the rows, I have to use Page scrollbar and move it down. Then again I can see table scroll and can move below. This means i have to use 2 scrollbars for viewing the rows. Any way to avoid this?

Second issue: If I don't use  tag proper page level scroll does not appear. A very long scroll thumb appears (for example if I use semantic page tag as shown below, the scroll thumb is as good as body in length, with very little area to move as track)

**ABC.xml**

```
    <mvc:View controllerName="com.ABC" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"  xmlns:semantic="sap.m.semantic">

     //Here instead of semantic page if I use   
     // <Page class="sapUiNoMargin maxPage" showHeader="false"> it works fine 
        with proper page scroll of nice thumb length 

    <semantic:SemanticPage busy="{sharedApp>/oBusy/busy}" busyIndicatorDelay="{sharedApp/oBusy/delay}" id="page" showSubHeader="false">
        <semantic:content>
            <core:Fragment id="ordersGrowlNotifier" fragmentName="com.ASD" type="XML"/>

            <IconTabBar id="order-tabs" select="onTabChangeEvent" expandable="false" class="tabs">
                <items>
                    <IconTabFilter text="Order" key="cart_tab">
                        <content>
                            <VBox>
                                <items>
                                 <core:Fragment fragmentName="com.Order" type="XML"/>
                                </items>
                            </VBox>
                        </content>
                    </IconTabFilter>

                    <IconTabFilter id="orderdetails-tab-track"  key="track_tab" text="Track" visible="{orderMenu>/TrackVisible}" >
                        <content>
                            <VBox>
                                <items>
                                    <core:Fragment fragmentName="com.XYZ" type="XML"/>
                                </items>

                            </VBox>
                        </content>
                    </IconTabFilter>

                </items>

            </IconTabBar>
        </semantic:content>
    </semantic:SemanticPage>

</mvc:View>
```

Comment: It is hard to tell what is wrong here. From my experience, it is related to the css that you have.

Comment: It is a layout issue, if the page height is greater then the screen size automatically the page scroll appears. Same applies to Table. Either you can decrease the visible rows of the table based on the screen size.